# Spark temporary table is not shown in beeline

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a spark cluster at AWS EMR and try to start the following code with thrift-server:

```
...
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate());
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(jsc);
JavaRDD<Person> people = jsc.textFile("people.txt").map(
  new Function<String, Person>() {
    public Person call(String line) throws Exception {
      ...
    }
});
DataFrame schemaPeople = hiveContext.createDataFrame(people, Person.class);
schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people_temp");
schemaPeople.saveAsTable("people");

HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(hiveContext);
...
```

I run this code with a command:
`sudo ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --jars /home/ec2-user/some.jar --class spark.jobs.thrift.ThriftServerInit`

After thrift server was started I connect to it with beeline:
`!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001`, run `show tables;` and get a result:

```
+--------------+--------------+--+
|  tableName   | isTemporary  |
+--------------+--------------+--+
| people       | false        |
+--------------+--------------+--+
```

I expect to see a temporary table `people_temp` too. Why `people_temp` is absent?

Answer (score 0):

On latest Spark 1.6.* I found that needed to explicitly set the configuration flag to single session to make it work with temp tables: spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true
Take a look at the migration guide
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-15-to-16
Hope this helps

Rod